# Code to dinamically change a select, to also work in Safari

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I'm using some code to be able to click on a button in a page, and load the next page with a hash in the URL, to use it to dinamically select certain filters from a form, this works in Chrome and Forefox, but not in Safari:

The button is a simple  tag that loads an URL with a hash at the end...For example "https://xxx/#Retail".

The code that selects an option from a form depending on this hash:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    $('select option:contains(' + hash + ')').attr('selected','selected').trigger('click');
    $('select option:contains(' + hash + ')').parent().trigger('click');
}
```

What's not compatible with Safari here?

Comment: Hook to the `change` event of the select, then trigger that instead

Comment: Which part doesn't work in Safari? does the option not get selected? or does your change event not fire?

Comment: Nothing gets selected in the form.

Comment: To add to @RoryMcCrossan's comment. Don't use the `click` event regardless as a user can change the option selected in a select element via the keyboard too... and there will not be a click. `change` will capture the event regardless how it was triggered by the user.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the select list? Just trying to ensure you are getting a match on the option with "etail".

Comment: Change seems to work well.